# Could not find the correct Provider<FontSizeHandler> above this HomePage Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have to *IconButton* in **AppBar** and on the press I want to change the font size using **Providers** Package.
But I am constantly getting this error message:

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this
> HomePage Widget
>
> This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not
> include the provider of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
>
> - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
>
>   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route,
>   then   other routes will not be able to access that provider.

**HomePage.dart**

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<FontSizeHandler>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => FontSizeHandler(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
           
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
              onPressed: () {
                Provider.of<FontSizeHandler>(context, listen: false)
                    .increaseFont();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Consumer<FontSizeHandler>(builder: (context, myFontHandler, _) {
          return Container(
            child: AutoSizeText(
              kDummy,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: myFontHanlder.fontSize),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**FontChangeHandler.dart**

```
    class FontSizeHandler extends ChangeNotifier {
      double fontSize = 15;
      void increaseFont() {
        fontSize = fontSize + 2;
        notifyListeners();
      }

  void decreaseFont() {
    fontSize = fontSize - 2;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to access information you are creating on the same `build` method.

Before you "Consume" the provider, you need to build a Widget to make sure the creation of your provider took place.

If you dont want to create a new StateLess/StateFull Widget, add a [Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) like this:

```
...body: Builder(
     builder:(BuildContext context)=> Consumer<FontSizeHandler>(...))
```

This way, [Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) will make sure that your parent provider gets build before consuming it.

**EDIT:**

The answer above will do if you want the Provider to be Consumable in the same Stateful/Stateless Widget.

If you need the Provider to be accessed from anywhere in your Flutter App, make sure that you create the Provider before the MaterialApp/CupertinoApp.

Comment: Have you tried placing the `ChangeNotifierProvider<FontSizeHandler>`  before your MaterialApp? This way it should be available on your whole app. 
Its hard to answer this without knowing your app structure.

Comment: I used MultiProvider in runApp() method as mentioned in the documentation and it worked. Thank you anyway

Answer (score -1):

Had a similar issue. Solved by importing the provider from the file tree and not the app package.

I was doing this:

```
import '../fav_provider.dart';
```

Instead of this.

```
import 'package:gmartapp/fav_provider.dart';
```

Just make sure your provider is imported from your app package not your file tree.

Comment: Importing in both ways are the same, may you just not hit save to take affect(Hot reload), the OP problem is mostly about creating and consuming provider at same time(in one place), But thanks for your attention.